# Are changes to Docker images automatically transferred to deployed containers?

Tags: docker

As I understand, there is a Docker Server hosting images (containers) of the apps. Then I can deploy these images to whatever infrastructure I want, be it locally or cloud. Am I right?

Assume this diagram

[image: http://i64.tinypic.com/ldsvd.png]

If I modify the apps, is it enough to just modify them in the Docker Server, and then the changes will be transferred (automatically?) to the deployed containers? Or do I need to modify each instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Docker image is comparable to a Class. A Docker container is comparable to an Object. A container is an instance of an image.

You can run 20 containers from the same image. All 20 containers will be the same (although you could pass environment variables to each container to modify behaviour).

An image contains services (e.g. a web server - NGINX)

An image contains files (e.g. the HTML files NGINX will be serving)

Let's call this image XXX

You can then run a container from image XXX which will actually start NGINX inside the container - think of a container as a virtual machine.

The wonderful thing about images is that they can be pulled and pushed and tagged (similar to `git pull` and `push`).

So now I can push an image to docker hub and then pull that image from anywhere and then run containers from that image.

Now it is very quick for me to deploy my web application. I just `docker pull` it, run a container and job done. The only dependency that must be installed on the server I am deploying to is Docker itself, nothing else is required.

I could make multiple images. For example I might have a front end image and a back end image. I can stand up a container for both images and the containers can talk to each other. This allows me to separate concerns. The front end code and dependent software is in one container, the backend code and dependent software is in another container.

I might want to run multiple front end containers on different servers and then stand up a load balancer to direct traffic to those containers. I could even put the load balancer in a container! This is great for scaling, just make sure your front end containers are stateless :)

Note if you are using multiple containers then consider using Docker Compose alongside Docker. Docker Compose is basically just a YAML file that takes the same arguments as the command line arguments.

Docker Compose however offers a few nice features like `docker-compose logs` which allows you to view the logs of all containers.

Comment: if I modify the base image, do I need to relaunch every container so that they get the latest update? or the changes are somehow transferred to them?

Comment: if you change the base image then you need to docker pull that image again, kill all running containers and then run them again

Comment: one last thing, what I called the  Docker Server in my picture, it is really the Docker Hub you mentioned, right?

Comment: yes your docker server is docker hub ... https://hub.docker.com/ ... create an account there then you can push and pull images to / from it. It is free (but I think you pay for privacy - although I believe you get one private docker repo for free).

Comment: Firstly, I don't have time to review all the changes you are making - you pick on me soo much - secondly, one or two of your edits recently appear to have been harmful - either I don't understand the system correctly or you harmfully changed a regex in one of my answers and in another answer you deleted a block of text that was useful. Please leave your changes to grammar only. you must be so bored to spend so much time doing this, why not spend your time writing a website or something instead of harassing people here. You've just cost me 15 minutes. not happy.

Comment: @danday74: hi Dan. The Meta question you posted about my editing was deleted (by a diamond mod) while I was composing a substantial reply, so sadly the community at large will not benefit from seeing that conversational exchange. I asked a mod to undelete it, but they felt it best to leave it deleted. My offer above to hold a chat session with you is still open (they're still public and moderated of course).

Comment: thanks for the offer but my rate is £400 a day - either I get paid or I spend it with family, I don't have the time to discuss in depth similarly I don't have the time to review all your edits so feel free to continue editing my posts but less of an avalanche and more evenly paced would be appreciated

Comment: My offer to discuss is merely that, an offer - take it or leave it. My best guess is you'd have gotten an extremely poor reception on Meta, and while I don't approve of the phenomenon, you put yourself at risk of a downvote storm on your primary account (the so-called [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)). The diamond mod did you a favour by preventing that from happening.

Comment: You received some [good advice from Suraj Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364434/complaint-about-an-over-zealous-moderator#comment564114_364434), who is a valued part of the voting/curating community here. Please take his/her suggestion.

Comment: Do note my advice above, **please use notifications in future**. My handle looks like this: `@halfer`. Auto-complete is available - type a couple of characters and use tab. This activates the notifications widget in the top bar, which you will see just now, because I am commenting on your question.

Comment: Finally, if you can make more of an effort with your questions, that would be appreciated. My edit suggestions have trimmed "hope this helps" and "thanks" chatty material, and fixed case errors. To the best of my knowledge, my edits are welcomed by the community at large - if there is any doubt about what sort of edits should be made, please ask a Meta question, or consult old Meta questions.