# Is Single Page Application suitable for a CRM?

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp, crm, single-page-application

I would like your opinion on an web architecture matter of an average complexity.

**Context**: I have to build a custom CRM (Client Relationship Management) web platform for my company, that will pretty much perform only CRUD operations on entities such as clients, contracts, invoices, etc. As well, it should handle user management like registration, authentication and authorization (roles for users to define which type of actions they are allowed to perform). Here's the [data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjX4f.jpg) if you'd like a more detailed idea.

**Constraints**: I'm obligated, on the server side, to use:

- CakePHP 2.7 (*PHP 5.5*)
- MySQL 5.5

For the client side, I'm free to use whatever front-end web framework and library components in HTML, CSS and Javascript without any browser restrictions.

**Concern**: My main focus is the client-sever separation of concern, this is why I'm leaning on using the SPA approach. I would like to avoid as much as possible rendering views on the backend by using CakePHP template files *(.ctp)* . If possible, I'd even like to make by back-end almost entirely agnostic of the client side.

Except serving the initial html, css and js app files, I would like to use my back-end to serve as a entire Json REST API for **EVERY** CRUD operation that the client would consume through Ajax calls. I'm considering using AngularJS to handle all the MVVM client part.

**Question**: Is Single Page Aplication suited for this approach? What would you do? Any link or documentation would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your insight on the matter!

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly biased on my answer but I've worked a bit so far with [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) on the front-end and Node on the back-end. If you're going to supply JSON with a REST API then it should work the same no matter what you choose for your front-end.

Angular allows for really simple application of the MVC pattern. As such it's very easy to use whatever logic attached to the front-end. There are many tutorials and examples out there [for A&A](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.9446s33oy) although I've used and recommend JWT's for this since your API will serve JSON in (almost) everything and it's really  easy to attach to the Auth header on every request (with services).

Angular has the $http methods which allow basic POST and GET to whatever URL you supply, handling error and success easily aswell.

Besides the interaction with the server, it has several useful and neat ways to show the information on your Browser, such has user info, role, etc. with the use of double curly braces {{user.name}} for example.

Any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Have you done a similar project ? If so, how did you handle DOM manipulation ?

Comment: Yes, I'm developing one right now actually! Haven't had to manipulate DOM so far but a quick research lead me to this: http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/ Directives seem the way to go on that but that link explains it pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

If you can do an Api Rest with cakePhp, angular is a good option to do your front-end.

I advice you to use $resource with your api rest. It's more efficiant that $http.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that !

Answer (score 1):

Employed by a large reputable company, we had to do the same. We built a large SPA using ui.router to handle routing. ui.router claims to be the 'de facto' angular routing solution and indeed it is good and the most mature solution.

We've got Angular front end and Node backend but front end and back end, as you say, are entirely agnostic.

To further separate concerns you should consider Dockerising your solution, web files and web server in one container, talking to your backend in other container.

PS If you are not familiar with docker and you want a very quick overview see:

[Are changes to Docker images automatically transferred to deployed containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304640/are-changes-to-docker-images-automatically-transferred-to-deployed-containers)

I appreciate you may be restricted from using Docker, but if not, it's amazing!

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept but never got the opportunity to use it. Seems awesome but I doubt they'll tag along with that. Thanks for the ui.router advice though !